# Orthodox Camps in Spanish Speaking World

Tags: travel, summer

I am a 17 year old in my 6th year of learning Spanish, and would love to utilize my skills.  Therefore I ask you: are there any opportunities you know of for a nice, Orthodox boy in any Spanish speaking country?  I would like to be a counselor, but a camper would also work.  I want something for Spanish-speakers, not something for tourists.  I would like thrice daily davening and kosher food, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the responses....I would prefer not Chabad though.

Comment: Matthew, you can still use godaven.com to search for Orthodox communities; like I said, this Madrid place looks promising, or could probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: Soy un de 17 años de edad en mi año sexto de aprender español, y adorar utilizar mis habilidades. ¿Por lo tanto le pregunto: hay cualquier oportunidad que usted sabe de para un chico agradable y Ortodoxo en cualquier español que habla país? Querría ser un consejero, pero un campista también trabajaría. Deseo algo para español-Altavoces, no algo para turistas. Querría davening tres veces diario y alimento kosher, por supuesto

Comment: My cousin spent some time studying in Spain.  I'll try and remember to ask him next time I get a chance to find out what the community there is like.

Answer (score 4):

Hm. My guess is you could try the various Chabad-Lubavitch installations in Latin America. You could go to godaven.com and search for *Jabad*. (Including one Spanish-speaking shul in Florida ... you learn something new every day!)

There's also this *Or HaYeladim* ("light of the children") synagogue north of Madrid; I suspect their administration would be able to tell you about summer camps in the area.

UPDATE: msh210 pointed out Chabad has a worldwide camp locator; looks like there's a few in Argentina for starters. That beats any of my ideas.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/280451/jewish/Camp-Directory.htm

Comment: @msh210, yep that's the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Mexico has a Huge Syrian community how you would get a Job I don't know.